# Need help in finding short circuit

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, debugging, troubleshooting, power-amplifier

I designed a basic power amplifier powered by +12V/-12V. During the breadboard testing phase, the bench power supply indicated a stable voltage of +12V/-12V and a current draw of 150mA. After receiving the ordered PCB and soldering all the components onto it, I connected the power amp to my home bench. However, my home bench reached the current limit, and the voltage dropped to around 3.20V.
[image]

Despite using a multimeter to troubleshoot by placing one pin on the +/-/GND and probing through all other components with the second pin, I couldn't pinpoint the issue. I suspect that the problem lies internally within the PCB itself.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide feedback on my schematics and highlight any design flaws I may have overlooked.

Schematic:
[image]

PCB:
**Top layer**

[image]

**Bottom layer**

[image]

Comment: It isn't a direct short or the voltage would be lower. Most likely a partial short through a component. Here is a troubleshooting method, but it works best on hard shorts. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494327/debugging-a-multilayer-pcb/495803#495803

Comment: I don’t think -12V should be going to pin 7 on the TL081 nor +12V to pin 4. I suspect you have these reversed. Simply remove your TL081 from the socket and see if the overload disappears.

Answer (score 2):

As Kartman pointed out, pin 7 and pin 4 are reversed. Upon correcting this issue, the IC overload disappeared.