# What is expected resistance of MCU power supply pins?

Tags: microcontroller, testing

I've assembled several identical boards and one of them does not work. Visual inspection does not show any bridges, but it is hard to tell with LQFP pitch. The voltage on power rail was zero. I've removed 3.3V DC-DC chip and measured the resistance between power rail and ground. 0.1 Ohm seems to indicate a short, so I am hesitant to apply external voltage to it. The board has one MCU, EEPROM, and couple of RS485 transceivers.

Any suggestions how I can find a problem other than de-soldering chips one by one?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494327/debugging-a-multilayer-pcb/495803#495803

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am hesitant to apply external voltage to it

As long as it is current-limited, it should be OK.

> Visual inspection does not show any bridges, but it is hard to tell with LQFP pitch.

You need a good microscope. See smartphone repair videos for some suggestions - they will be pretty good, as the component sizes on smartphones are about the smallest you'll find anywhere.

> Any suggestions how I can find a problem other than de-soldering chips one by one?

Get a thermal camera, power up the board, look at where the heat is. That's where the short is. That's about the fastest way to find shorts on any board, and that's what makes people who repair consumer electronics able to keep their productivity high - and ultimately to make ends meet.

There are many other ways of short tracing on a board, but the first step should almost always be to have a look with a thermal camera.

I highly suggest having a look at YouTube videos of people who competently do component-level repairs of consumer devices such as smartphones. [STS Telecom](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC39yMXOL0ubFxLWwF1RwelA) is my favorite although there are many others.

> What is the expected resistance of MCU power supply pins?

An ohm at least on desktop-type CPUs, on MCUs it'll be orders of magnitude more, exact value depending on the rated voltage at the pin you're measuring.

Comment: "on MCUs it'll be orders of magnitude more" that's what I thought too. I guess leakage current of 40+ clamp diodes can bring it down, but not that much

Comment: +1 STS Telecom practically runs a clinic on component-level repairs of HDI boards. You can also try to follow the current path with a multimeter on mV range. Shorted capacitors sometimes happen too. And boards that come with shorts in the etch.

Comment: Just a side note here. Measuring resistance between input voltage to ground on an IC is a good indicator of whether there is a short.

Comment: If the resistance measured is on the order of 0.1 ohm, it might take quite a lot of current to get any significant heating. Sounds like it's a metal short (solder bridge?), not a short through a failed semiconductor.

Comment: @Colin I of course used that technique and sometimes you still need to do it. But a thermal camera and a current limited supply is such a powerful combo that in this day and age not having it is outright waste of time IMHO.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Of course :) No worries. Thermal camera is probably the best tool for root cause analysis, along with an x-ray perhaps. Your answer is still really good and I upvoted. I only made that comment because thermal cameras may not always be accessible. I usually measure input to ground as a sanity check. It's funny, sometimes if you x-ray a chip that is shorted, you can see a miniature explosion and the silicon inside looks like sharp spikes inside the package.

Answer (score 4):

As MCUs and other ICs are not resistances, they have no defined resistance. And on a PCB, there are many components over the supply and ground nodes.

Only if you try measuring a board supply and ground with a multimeter resistance, you get **some value** what the multimeter has calculated for you based on how much current flows and at what voltage, but it clearly cannot be a resistance.

But, as you measure 0.1 ohms, that's a short circuit.

It can be an error of manufacturing the PCB, or error that makes a solder bridge, or damaged or incorrectly mounted component, or just a broken bypass capacitor you cannot visually determine to be shorting.

How to find the problem is interesting.

You can use a microscope to find PCB manufacturing errors, solder bridges, incorrectly mounted components, or cracked ceramic capacitors.

You could use a sensitive resistance meter and pin-point the place with least milliohms between supply and ground. Or apply very low voltage with safe current limiting and measure where voltage drops happen or where there is least voltage between supply and ground.

A thermal camera might help as the short circuit may heat up or the traces leading to it.

While shorting PCB tracks may happen, it may be a capacitor that is shorted as well.

If all else fails, try applying low voltage but with higher current limit, which may burn off a small short circuit, or at least heat up the shorting capacitor. It may not work, but if you only have a few prototypes and need all of them, this may work to revive it.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience it is unlikely to be an IC. More likely is a solder bridge or shorted capacitor.

You may be able to to determine where the short is by applying a low voltage from a current-limited power supply and measuring the voltage at various points on the PCB (it may only be millivolts variation) to see where the lowest voltage is. If the short is under a large pinout device such as a BGA you may need to X-ray the board or use a CT scan to see where the solder bridge is.

Another technique is to apply a low voltage then use an infra red camera (eg FLIR) to see where the hot-spot is. In the past there were liquid crystal films available that were used similarly to see hot spots.