How can I find where a short has occurred inside of a PCB?
I have designed a board in KiCad that I then had manufactured by JLCPCB. It has a ground plane and a 5V plane, which are shorted together. This does not appear in the schematic or PCB files. How can I locate the short, which is most likely inside of the 4-layer board?
I don't know what's causing it, but it's on an empty PCB.
Edit: The DRC does not give errors, and I do not have any fancy equipment.
Edit #2: JLCPCB put in a buried via that I did not ask for between the 5V and GND planes. The problem was fixed with a small drill bit.

connect a 6 V lead acid battery between the ground plane and the 5 V plane ... the short will evaporate

I ran 50A between it. I then noticed there was a short

Look at the layers/gerbers in your PCB layout tool and see if you can spot a place where 5V and GND are unintentionally connected (eg a GND via that should have pulled away from 5V). This happened to me before with JLCPCB and they pointed to the short in files I had uploaded.

You could use a smaller current if you have  a thermal imager, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/321060/117785

Voltage drop method documented in detail here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494327/debugging-a-multilayer-pcb/495803#495803

Hope it helps. https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/locating-shorts-on-power-planes-of-multi-layer-pcbs.html

What's your stack-up? It probably matters quite a bit.

And yeah I'm with @Ale..chenski here, if you can use some manner of thermal/IR camera they are awesome for this kind of stuff. Then you wouldn't need to crank the power up until there's smoke coming out (which is a fire hazard and unhealthy as well), but rather hook the PCB up to your current-limited bench supply, look for signs of heat and then slowly increase the current in a controlled manner until you see it. Super easy and won't fry the board, but you do need the equipment.

With one of these! I used to use one in my day job - it was ace!
Otherwise, if you can lay your hands on a FLIR, run a few amps through it and look for the hotspot.

With earlier versions of Kicad at least it was quite easy to forget to redraw the filled  zones after making some final improvements to the layout before generating the Gerber files. Especially if you don't run the design rules checker as the very last activity which,  by default, does this automatically. This happened to me once but the board manufacturer found it and sent a picture of the mess it created.

@jsotola I vividly remember a day during an internship at DESY in the 1980s. The Lab technician had produced a short on some PCB he had soldered and couldn't find it easily; he proudly announced to us interns "now I'll show you how to burn out a short!" When he connected the second cable, the hefty 19" lab power supply changed its hum noticeably and the cables sagged and started to smoke :-). Interestingly, that, too, was a diagnostic: It must be a substantial short close to the power connectors. He discovered that he had dropped a blob of solder where it didn't belong.

Slightly tangential: Does the Design Rules Checker (DRC) give an error to that effect?  If not, does re-exporting the gerbers after that produce something different, having re-done the pours like @6v6gt said?  I usually try to have the error-checkers clean before I export anything.  (including the ERC on the schematic as well)  I've gotten away with a few things before, mostly on-purpose, but it's like art: it's okay to break a rule, but only if you know what the rule is, why it exists, and why you're breaking it now.  If you don't understand those three things, that's when you get bitten.

Do you have an extra board that you can send me? 99% chance that I can find it by injecting a current and following the voltage drops.

You could connect an audio signal generator and run as much audio current as possible through the short, at something like 400 Hz or 1 kHz. Then make a pickup coil (often the iron core and coil from an old relay works well).  Connect this to an audio amplifier with a gain of few thousand, connect some headphones, and you can trace the path of the current flow.
This technique is used in many labs to find ground loops as well.

nice - you learn something new every day.

Do you have a suggestion where to get high current audio signals?

@Jackedak a hifi amp - but not a valuable one.

@ChrisH I don't know, it sounds like a perfect opportunity to test out one of these? https://www.theabsolutesound.com/articles/western-electric-91e-integrated-amplifier-and-300b-tube/

I'm able to get a good signal with my tek awg that puts out about 5 volts into 50 ohms, so shorted delivers about 200 mA. Spend your time on high gain for your pickup probe.

If you apply a significant current (several amperes or more) then you can follow the path to the short by measuring voltage gradients with a multimeter on a low range (10uV or 100uV resolution, more resolution will allow working with lower resistance conductors at less current).
The voltage will change in a monotonic manner in the path to the short. If the voltage is not changing much or is going in the opposite direction then you are not moving closer to the short. You can probe the internal planes wherever there is a via.
Chance are very good that it's visible in your Gerber files. Mounting holes, perhaps.. or a copper repour that got missed.

A very simple variation of this approach that is widely used by repair technicians is to pour isopropyl alcohol over the board and then apply a more modest current.  Since the boiling point of isopropyl is 180F, the location of the short will cause the alcohol to immediately boil while the board is still at a low enough temperature that you are unlikely to cause permanent damage to the board.

If you run a significant current through the board the contact spot may get warmer then the rest of the board since it has most likely the highest resistance in the path of the current.
The best method to see the temperature would be a thermal camera, although you could also use the tips of your fingers to narrow down the region/via.

Caution Nr.1: Disconnect your power supply first before touching!
Caution Nr.2: It may be HOT!


This is a very standard trick in electronics repair. Obviously it's a bit dangerous -- ideally use a power supply with current limiting, so you can turn it up until the hotspot is apparent, rather than dead shorting it until something catches fire.

Use a freezing spray to frost the board and the frost melts faster in regions of high current flow.

Start drilling out vias while watching the resistance between 5V and ground.
You'll see an increases of resistance when drilling on any via that's involved in the short.
Measure resistance by applying a known current and measuring the voltage developed between the two planes.

You could try to isolate the short using the hardware equivalent of a binary chop process. That is with a hacksaw and maybe sandpaper to clean the edges. If you do it carefully, you'd need only one board.

I have no experience with KiCad in this regard, but I once got a PCB with the same issue.
It turned out that I had a used a vendor component (a USB connector) that used milling instead of drills for the mounting posts. Eagle did not calculate any spacing for the VCC layer to these milled mounting holes which were supposed to be connected to GND, and thus they got accidentally shorted when the areas were plated. The short was not visible in the Gerbers, only as a logical end result from missing copper-to-hole distance.

Yes, mounting holes are often where shorts occur.

Have you manually checked the netlist? KiCad create and understand netlist or use the highlight tool in either schematic or PCB view select one pin on the 5V net and check what other traces and pins are selected.

When I managed to design a PCB with small short (tiny bridge formed on the corners of two tracks) my boss recommended to use miliohmometer which produced beeping sound with variable pitch, the smaller resistance, the higher pitch.  When in use, for example you could place one probe to one end of a trace and it was possible to hear the difference (thus, variable resistance of it) when placing other probe along a track, even quite thick one. Very useful for finding unknown paths of current.
Now as I recovered this memory I want to build one!

Most often you can talk to your manufacturer and see if they have a flying probe with a continuity test.
Seeing as how this is JLCPCB, and you probably have your boards it's a little late for that.
A lot of times you can get out of DMM and do a continuity test on the PCB. This will work if you have an unloaded PCB.
If your PCB is loaded, One good thing is to turn the design on with a current limit and try and trace where the voltage is going this can be difficult if you have regulators on the board. Sometimes you can turn it on briefly with the scope before you do any damage and find the rails that are close to 0 volts.
Another thing to do is check the Gerber files and see if there are any errors with nets touching each other.
But you should definitely be able to see which nets are connected to which with a DMM in continuity mode

I said that 5V and GND are connected. And it is unloaded.

You could run some current though the PCB and see where it heats up

You beat bet is the Gerbers it's unlikely that it's a MFG error, but possible

Sometime back I had a square pad rotated 45 due to a bug in the manufacturers Gerber processor and the unusual way diptrace exported it.

Check for solder bridges. Or, feel for which part of the PCB is hotter. You can use a PCB microscope ($5 on Walmart) to see for solder bridges.
