Short circuit fault finding by Kelvin 4 wire method
In several YouTube videos on repairing notebooks or smartphones I have seen that the 4-wire Kelvin method is used to find the location of a short circuit in an electronic board, in practice, with the multimeter you look for the smallest voltage between the terminal of a certain component and the ground and it is assumed that it is the component that caused the short circuit. Now I wonder, does this method have a scientific value? If there are multiple components in parallel then they will all have the same voltage and therefore it will be necessary to extract each of them and test it individually or am I wrong? Furthermore, for there to be some component with the lowest voltage it means that all the others are on separate lines from the main one otherwise they would be in parallel. I ask you for an explanation of this method perhaps with the help of some graphs. Thanks in advance.

The core idea of the 4-wire method you're watching is to measure the resistance of traces to locate a short. If you assume the traces have zero resistance than measuring them won't work, but in reality copper has a finite and measurable resistance.

See my answer to this similar question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494327/debugging-a-multilayer-pcb/495803#495803

Mattman944 ,In your method you inject a current from one side of the board and look for the highest voltage drop, why? Shouldn't we look for the lowest voltage drop (lowest resistance) that causes the short circuit?

Whether the voltage is higher or lower will depend on the reference point. In any case, voltage drop = current flow, follow the current flow to the short.

Mattman944,But if I take ground as a reference then the closer I get to the short circuit the more the resistance decreases and consequently also the voltage drop or am I wrong? could you make a drawing to understand when the voltage rises or when the voltage drops in proximity to a short circuit? I'm a little confused...

@Electronics2015 - there are drawings in the linked question/answer.

@Mattman944 - I just saw the drawings but I can't understand why it is necessary to look for the highest voltage when a short circuit is associated with the lowest voltage. Could you explain it to me better? Thanks

"If there are multiple components in parallel then they will all have the same voltage"
No. This is a simplification that we often use when analyzing circuits. In fact every connection, and in particular every trace, and even the power planes in a PCB has/have resistance.
Under normal operating conditions, those traces have measurable but small voltage drop. If there is a short and we force a relatively large current, say 1A to flow rather than much smaller currents that might normally be flowing, the voltage drops become much larger (and being DC as well) much easier to measure.
However what is true is that if the connections branch off and there is a short somewhere along that branch, connections after that branch will tend to show no more voltage drop.

Schematic diagrams do not lend themselves easily to representing 2D current flow in planes, but consider this simplified circuit where each 0.1 ohm resistor represents a trace resistance. In reality they will vary:
In the top diagram we have a number of bypass capacitors operating properly. The voltage at one end of the chain is the same as at the other end.
In the bottom diagram I've replaced one of the capacitors with a 0.01 ohm short. You can see that the voltage drops as you go to the right until you find the short, then after that it remains a the same value.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Ok.What is the physical reason why after the short circuit the voltage no longer shows drops?

Because there is little or no current flowing. Assuming the voltage source is to the left, the current flows in a loop from the source to the short. The right hand loop has little or no current flowing, thus little to no voltage drop.
